# fill JSON response in config object dynamically in node js

Tags: node.js, json

I have a `JSON` response filled with config data, i want to fill my config variables with respective elements from the `JSON` response dynamically without writing a line to assign each and every variable.

code that retrieves my `JSON` file:

```
configObj = require("./Config.js");

ws_server.getConfigHTTPRequest(function(data){

    jsonObject = JSON.parse(data.toString().replace("//","",));

        var keys = Object.keys(jsonObject);
        keys.forEach(function(key){

        //here i want to assign the values to their respective values in the 
        //config object according to the key value
        //i tried this : configObj.key = jsonObject[key], but it doesnt 
        //assign the values although JSON object keys are named the same 
        // as my config object variables

       console.log(key +': '+ jsonObject[key])

        });  

});
```

Here is my config object:

```
module.exports = {
    coldfusion_WS : "ws://192.168.#####/cfusion/cfusion/", 
    readerURI: "tmr://192.168.###",
    serialPort: "COM5",
    KIOSKID: "3",
    kiosktype: "IN",
    baudRate: 9600 ,
    coldFusionIP:"192.168.###",
    coldFusionPort:"81",
    JAR_path:"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/KiosksClient/javaapi/",
    applicationName:"KioskServerV2",
    HTTPPrintUrl:"http://192.168.###/IQNFLOW/kiosk_files/",
    PdfFilePath:"C:/inetpub/wwwroot/KiosksClient/print_files/",
    PingReaderSleep:"6",
    readerPingAddress: "192.168.###" ,
    printerName:"USBPRN:Star TUP900 Presenter (TUP992)",
    printerThrearSleep:"30000" ,
    RFIDThreadSleep:"20" ,
    HTTPPath:"/KiosksServer/components/WS.cfc" ,
    GOUTIP:"172.16###" ,
    GINIP:"172.16.###" ,
    paperOut:16 ,
    doorOpen:4194304 ,
    paperLow:131072 ,
    paperNotPulled:2048 ,
    readerPower:"20",
    driverImagePath:"http://localhost:81/28010948_personal_092957.png" ,
    DriverRegWS:"http://localhost:81/driverregistrar/WS/cards.cfc",
    driverRegIP:"localhost"

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i simply had to use:

```
configObj[key] = jsonObject[key]
```

got insight after reading the following article : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you just want to copy every value in the incoming object into your config object, you can do that without a loop:

```
Object.assign(configObject, jsonObject)
```

See [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more details.